# How to read command line output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to open a batch file in **Nodejs** and read its output, while it is printing (**not** everything at once when the batch finished).

For example, like **Jenkins** / **Hudson**.

I'm aware that this will only work on **Windows**. Any complete example of how to do this will be helpful, as I'm pretty new to **Nodejs**.

Comment: ...only work on windows?  And what do you mean "while it is printing"?  You mean as a batch file is updated by some other process?

Comment: No, for example if I have the batch `ECHO hi
TIMEOUT 1
ECHO bye` First it will print hi, then the timeout message, and it will be updated as it is counting. Just like the command line does.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll be fine using [Node's child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run your command and monitor it's output as it prints.  This does not have any restrictions on Windows though, so I may be missing something in what you're asking.  Let me explain what you could do in hopes that it answers the question.

Imagine you have a file that outputs some text, but does so over time and not all at once.  Let's name this file `print-something.js`.  (I realize you've spoken about a batch file, but know that the `child_process` can execute any executable file.  So here I'll be running a JavaScript file via Node, but you could execute a batch file in the same way.)

**print-something.js**

```
var maxRuns = 5,
    numRuns = 0;

function printSomething() {
    console.log('some output');
    setTimeout(function() {
        numRuns++;
        if (numRuns < maxRuns) {
            printSomething();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

printSomething();
```

It's not really important what this file does, but if you study it you'll see it prints "some output" 5 times, but prints each statement with a 1 second gap in-between.  Running this from the command line (via `node print-something.js`) will result in:

> some output
>   some output
>   some output
>   some output
>   some output

So with that we have a file that outputs text in a delayed manner.  Turning our attention to the file that reads the output, we have this:

**monitor-output.js**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    command = spawn('node', ['print-something.js']);

command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

command.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

This file spawns a process `node print-something.js`, and then begins to inspect its standard output.  Each time it gets data, it prints it to the console.  Finally, when the execution has completed, it outputs the exit code.  Running `node monitor-output.js` results in:

> stdout: some output
>
> stdout: some output
>
> stdout: some output
>
> stdout: some output
>
> stdout: some output
>
> child process exited with code 0

Most likely you won't be printing the output of this file to the console, but that's what we're doing here just for illustration.  Hopefully this gives you an idea on how to monitor output of a file while it runs, and do what you will with it within the `child_process`.

Comment: Wow thanks for the complete answer! I will try this.